# creating a binary (.bin) file and read values from file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, binary

Hi i am trying to save text values as binary file and read from that file. i am using following code, i got the binary file in documents directory but when reading data from file only got some numbers please kindly help its urgent.
For writing

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self performSelector:@selector(tempDirectoryPath:) withObject:fileName_];
NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectoryPath);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath]) {
    NSLog(@"content =%@",data_);
    [data_ writeToFile:documentsDirectoryPath atomically:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

For reading i use the following code,

```
  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self performSelector:@selector(tempDirectoryPath:) withObject:fileName_];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath]) {
    NSMutableData *data_ = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentsDirectoryPath];

    return data_;
}
```

I got only numbers from the data_ .

How to read the .bin file correctly.?

I got the .bin file when extract get .bin.cpgz file.I can't open the file what is the reason ?Is anything wrong in code?
I am pass  string in this way:

```
[self writeData:@"test string is here" toFile:@"mf.bin"];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little late, but something like this might help you:

http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/475-How-to-use-NSKeyedArchiver-to-store-user-settings-on-the-iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to convert the data into something readable.

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This assumes originally the data you wrote was a NSString, if it was an object you would have to use the appropriate methods for that object.